# What is the name of this theorem from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

What is the name of the following theorem?

> Assume that $\{f_n\}$ is boundedly convergent on $[a, b]$ and suppose each $f_n$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a, b]$. Assume also that the limit function $f$ is Riemann-integrable on $[a, b]$. Then$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b f_n(x)\,dx = \int_a^b \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)\,dx = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx.$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the theorem 9.12 (Arzela) page 228 from Apostol's Mathematical analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is a variant of what is called the **bounded convergence theorem**.